# Docker compose error for invalid volume specification

Tags: mongodb, docker

Whenever I run a command on `docker compose up -d` I'm stuck on following error!

*docker-compose.yml*

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  mongo:
    container_name: "mernstackdb"
    image: mongo:5.0.8-focal
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - ./db:/data/db
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
```

*Error*

> Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification: 'C:\Users\Momin Riyadh\Desktop\momin-git\mern-stack\db:/data/db:rw': invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does
> not exist: c:\users\momin riyadh\desktop\momin-git\mern-stack\db

Comment: As mentioned in the error message, it seems `db` directory is not present in the current directory, so `./db` fails. Can you check that ?

Comment: It should be create automatic after run command, but didn't create!

Comment: It should not. Please create it manually.